# how can I convert a date string in the format "1969-03-07T05:00:00.000Z" to the output normally provided by new Date()

Tags: javascript

I am using `mongodb` to save my dates, and I do it by doing `new Date()`

how can I convert my date to string to the output of new Date()?

```js
let date="1969-03-07T05:00:00.000Z";
let new_date=new Date(date); //in my code it returns "Invalid date"
console.log(new_date);
console.log(new Date());
```

Comment: On my pc (regional settings I assume) your code seems to work.

Comment: Works in my Chrome. Please specify browser and platform that gives Invalid date

Comment: Your code is working! Why question?

Comment: @BambinoUA in nodejs this doesn't work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use [`Date.parse()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse) like:

```js
let date = "1969-03-07T05:00:00.000Z";
let new_date = new Date(Date.parse(date));
console.log(new_date);
console.log(new Date());
```